# Can Maven Deploy a Module to JBoss?

Tags: java, maven, jboss

We have a Maven project that we are using to deploy several wars to a JBoss server.  We recently noticed that one of the jars that a couple of our wars depend on, uses Xerial.  When Xerial starts it tries to load up a native driver, but only the first one successfully loads the native driver and the rest fail and fall back on a pure Java implementation because the native driver is already in a classloader.  We would really like to gain the performance back by being able to load the native driver on all the wars.

It looks to me like the best way to do this would be add the jar we depend on to the JBoss server as a module, and then have the services depend on it.

My question is, is there a way we can get our Maven build to do this?  Or are we going about this in the completely wrong way?

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using? One possible solution is to, in your deployment artifact, tell JBoss to use your deployed artifact's classpath before the application container's classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of looking, and talking to a couple of people who were much more familiar with JBoss-Maven interaction than me, it turns out the answer to my question is that it cant currently be done.  There is no Maven plugin capable of deploying a Module to JBoss.  This is largely in part to the fact that the modules are only loaded by JBoss when it starts, although if anyone is feeling particularly ambitious and wants to write their own Maven plugin, it could theoretically be worked around.

The answer @Robert Scholte left is a good one, and I learned from it, however it didn't actually answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

First and most of all Apache Maven is a ***build*** management tool. It will "package" a project and will normally upload it to a repository so it can be used by other projects.
However, there are plugins available, which can deploy to JBoss:

- http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/ (maybe combined with http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-packaging-maven-plugin/ )
- http://cargo.codehaus.org/

The first is JBoss specific, the latter a generic Java EE-container deploy plugin

Comment: For the sake of people reading this later, a currently maintained Maven JBoss Plugin is living at http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/.  The one you linked is more than two years dead.  I know about the plugins, I just don't know how to make them do this particular thing.

Comment: If the plugin at JBoss supersedes it, I can ask the mojo-team to retire that Maven plugin.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, but my Google-ing makes it look to me like there are a lot of people using old versions of JBoss.  Someone more familiar with this workflow than me should probably makes sure the new plugin works with the old JBoss versions before retiring it.

Comment: Retiring would only mean that the mojo team won't continue the development for this plugin and refers to JBoss. See the http://mojo.codehaus.org/plugins.html#Plugin_Graveyard. The released versions are still available in Maven Central, as well as the latest docs (even if they are 2 years old)

Comment: In that case, it definitely seems like it would be worth mentioning to them.  I see some similar plugins in the graveyard link you left.  Thanks for the exposure to that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to put your jar in the lib folder of the jboss server. This way, the jar is loaded in the shared classpath when the server starts. This will definitively serve the purpose.

Here is the jboss folder structured expleained.
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/dirs.html

Comment: I do know about this solution, but there is another team of people doing development on jar and it would be really nice if I could use Maven to keep it up to date and auto add it to other developers local instances during builds.

Comment: If the jar that you are talking about is not in a public maven repository, the only way for this jar to be available as a maven artifact to the other developers is to set-up your own Maven repository and install this jar as an artifact in that repository. All the other developers have to add the local repository to their Maven config.

Here is how you can setup a local Maven repository. http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3968

After you add this jar to the repository as a Maven artifact, it will be then injected as dependency in all your other maven projects.

Comment: We have this infrastructure set up, and Maven is fully capable of fetching the artifact and using it to build.  I feel like I'm not getting my question across very well.  Maven is fetching the jar, I just can't make maven put jar where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been marked as answered and the answer is that this currently is not possible, but I want to provide an alternative view. I am currently deploying Jboss modules to EAP 6.1 with Maven at my job. What we have done is use the maven-wagon plugin to scp the module to the tmp directory on the jboss server. I then use the maven-wagon plugin to issue a ssh command to the server to call the jboss-cli.sh script and tell it to perform a module installation. Here is a sample config:

```html
<profile>
   <id>uat</id>
   <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    <property>
     <name>switchEnv</name>
     <value>uat</value>
    </property>
   </activation>
   <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-beta-5</version>
      <executions>
       <execution>
        <id>upload-file-qa-server-one</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>upload-single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</fromFile>
         <url>scp://jboss@jboss-server-1/tmp/</url>
         <toFile>${project.name}.${project.packaging}</toFile>
        </configuration>
       </execution>
       <execution>
        <id>upload-file-qa-server-two</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>upload-single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</fromFile>
         <url>scp://jboss@jboss-server-2/tmp/</url>
         <toFile>${project.name}.${project.packaging}</toFile>
        </configuration>
       </execution>
       <execution>
        <id>install-module-qa-server-one</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>sshexec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <serverId>jboss-server-1</serverId>
                  <url>scp://jboss@jboss-server-1/tmp</url>
         <commands>
          <command>/opt/jboss/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command="module add --name=${project.name} --resources=/tmp/${project.name}.${project.packaging} --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api"</command>
          <command>sleep 5</command>
          <command>rm -f /tmp/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</command>
         </commands>
        </configuration>
       </execution>
       <execution>
        <id>install-module-qa-server-two</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>sshexec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <serverId>jboss-server-2</serverId>
                  <url>scp://jboss@jboss-server-2/tmp</url>
         <commands>
          <command>/opt/jboss/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command="module add --name=${project.name} --resources=/tmp/${project.name}.${project.packaging} --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api"</command>
          <command>sleep 5</command>
          <command>rm -f /tmp/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</command>
         </commands>
        </configuration>
       </execution>
      </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
  <profile>
```

Comment: The lastest Wildfly maven plugin has capabilities to execute `jboss-cli` commands directly, see: https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/execute-commands-example.html

Answer (score 0):

It´s not possible beause you have to use an OSGI approach.
To use maven try to work with OSGI within EAP, but it depends what you looking for. OSGI is supported since JBoss EAP 6.1.

If you are trying to work with EAI try to work with JBoss Fuse instead of EAP.
Then you will work with maven repositories, nexus or similar, hot deploy and all OSGI bundles stuff.