# how to deploy module with jboss-as-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jboss7.x

I've encounter following description, on JBoss forum, how to manually add application specific properties as module:
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath

I already have jboss-as-maven-plugin configured to deploy my application `foo.ear`.

Here, I've found similar/same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665111/1437865, and it looks like that this is not yet possible.

I am wondering if the situation has been changed from then?

Thank You

Comment: Are you looking to have a shared library across many deployments or just a dependency for your `foo.ear`?

Comment: Later one. I need module (e.g. com.foo.config) where I will place one properties file (e.g. foo.properties). Later in my foo.war or foo.ear I will need to add usage of this module by stating this in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. That way I would be able to access that foo.properties file through class-path.

Comment: It's probably easiest to put it in a JAR and include the JAR in your EAR/lib directory. Then you can access it on your class path.

Comment: Thnx, I've thought about that. But real problem lies in fact that this file (properties) must be configured outside my project. Those properties would be maintained by TechOps. It will contain properties (like URL's, etc.) to other components/3rd party services in much broader system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a module on JBoss using a CLI command requires to run something like this

```
module add --name=org.mysql --resources=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

Using Maven and jboss-as-maven-plugin you can directly run that command (or alternatively include it into a CLI batch script) into your POM  as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/execute-commands-example.html)